# How to generate all non-decreasing sequences with a maximum step of 1?

Tags: python, combinatorics

I am trying to get a list of every possible combination of the numbers 0-14 with certain constraints. I'm not exactly sure how to word this so let me explain.

- Each list will have a length of 15.
- The first list will be `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.
- The value at each index in each list cannot exceed the index itself, **and can be either the same as the previous number, or one higher than the previous number**.
- The final list will be `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]`.

I am looking to get a list of lists that contains all possible sequences with these constraints (e.g. one possible sequence would be `[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8]` ).

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: interesting problem

Comment: Actually made a mistake in the original post, I have edited the post to reflect this additional constraint.

Comment: Does the order of the lists matter?

Comment: how is `itertools.permutations` not working

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus "The value of each index in each list cannot exceed the value of its index"

Comment: The order does not matter. I'm trying to accomplish this using base python and no modules/libraries.

Answer (score 6):

Since the first list element is always 0, we have two choices for each remaining element; should it equal the previous element, or be one higher? That gives 2^14 different combinations.

To generate them, we can take the product of 14 copies of `(0, 1)`, and convert each to their sequence of partial sums using [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```py
import itertools

def solution(n):
    for p in itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=n):
        yield (0,) + tuple(itertools.accumulate(p))
```

Example:

```py
>>> for p in solution(3):
...     print(p)
... 
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 2, 2)
(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not as elegant (or well performing) as @kaya3's answer but this is a more intuitive approach for me. The basic idea is to recurse on the a list that has a certain starting integer and the remaining length.

```
def next(i, n):
    if n <= 1:
        return [[i]]
    else:
        without_increment = list(next(i, n-1))
        with_increment = list(next(i+1, n-1))
        return map(lambda l: [i] + l, without_increment + with_increment)

n = 3
list(next(0, n))
```

Output

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
```